# Wordpress button in wo-xml feed administration not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Problem is in administration console of wordpress in plugin 'woocommerce xml feeds'. There is button to add parameter for category. This button do nothing when I click it.

I tried to contact the author of plugin, he only told me to check debug console, but there is nothing. He also told me that function of this button depends on jQuery.

This is the button element:

```
<span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm add-param" data-par="80">Přidat parametr</span>
```

The whole PHP file for context:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * @package   woo_xml_feeds      
 * @author    Vladislav Musilek
 * @license   GPL-2.0+
 * @link      http://musilda.cz
 * @copyright 2014 Vladislav Musilek
 *
 * Version 1.0.0
 *  
 */


if(isset($_POST['update'])){

  //Save Heureka.sk Shipping values
  $this->save_heureka_delivery($name = 'woo_heureka_delivery');

  //Save Heureka.cz CPC value
  $this->save_single_option('heureka-cpc','heureka-cpc');




/**
 * Save Heureka category
 */  
  $heureka_assing_categories = get_option('woo_heureka_assing_categories');
    if(empty($heureka_assing_categories)){ $heureka_assing_categories = array(); }


  $heureka_excluded_categories = get_option( 'woo_heureka_excluded_categories');
    if(empty($heureka_excluded_categories)){ $heureka_excluded_categories = array(); }


  $heureka_categories_cpc = get_option( 'woo_heureka_categories_cpc');
    if(empty($heureka_categories_cpc)){ $heureka_categories_cpc = array(); }  



    foreach($_POST['termid'] as $key => $item){


    if(!empty($_POST['heurekaid'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['heurekaid'][$key])){
      $heureka_assing_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]] = $_POST['heurekaid'][$key];
    }else{
      if(!empty($heureka_assing_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]])){
         unset($heureka_assing_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]]);
      }
    }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['excluded'][$key])){
      $heureka_excluded_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]] = $_POST['termid'][$key];
    }else{
      if(!empty($heureka_excluded_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]])){
         unset($heureka_excluded_categories[$_POST['termid'][$key]]);
      }
    }


        if(!empty($_POST['termvar'][$key])){
          $heureka_categories_cpc[$_POST['termid'][$key]] = $_POST['category_cpc'][$key];
        }else{
          if(!empty($heureka_categories_cpc[$_POST['termid'][$key]])){
            unset($heureka_categories_cpc[$_POST['termid'][$key]]);
          }
        }




    }


  update_option( 'woo_heureka_assing_categories', $heureka_assing_categories );
  update_option( 'woo_heureka_excluded_categories', $heureka_excluded_categories );
  update_option( 'woo_heureka_categories_cpc', $heureka_categories_cpc );




  //Parametry pro kategorie
  $cat_params = get_option( 'woo_heureka_cat_params');
  if(empty($cat_params)){ $cat_params = array(); }

    foreach($_POST['termvar'] as $key => $item){

      $cat_params[$item]['term_id'] = $item;

      $cat_params[$item]['parametry'] = array();

      if(!empty($_POST['nazev_parametru_'.$item])){
        foreach($_POST['nazev_parametru_'.$item] as $lit => $var){

          $cat_params[$item]['parametry'][$lit]['nazev_parametru']   = $_POST['nazev_parametru_'.$item][$lit];
          $cat_params[$item]['parametry'][$lit]['hodnota_parametru'] = $_POST['hodnota_parametru_'.$item][$lit];

        }
      }
    }

  update_option( 'woo_heureka_cat_params', $cat_params );


  if(isset($_GET['catoffset'])){
    wp_redirect(admin_url().'admin.php?page=heureka-cz&catoffset='.$_GET['catoffset']);
  }else{
    wp_redirect(admin_url().'admin.php?page=heureka-cz');
  }

} 






$cat_params = get_option( 'woo_heureka_cat_params');
//Get heureka cz categories 
$heureka_categories          = get_option( 'woo_heureka_categories');
$heureka_assing_categories   = get_option( 'woo_heureka_assing_categories');
$heureka_excluded_categories = get_option( 'woo_heureka_excluded_categories');
$heureka_categories_cpc      = get_option( 'woo_heureka_categories_cpc');



$catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC')); 
$cat_list = custom_taxonomy_walker('product_cat');

$use_select2 = get_option( 'woo_xml_feed_use_select2' );

/**
 * Cat pagging
 *
 */  
$limit = 50;
if(isset($_GET['catoffset'])){
  $catstart = (($_GET['catoffset'] * $limit) - $limit)+1;
  $catend = $_GET['catoffset'] * $limit;
}else{ 
  $catstart = 1;
  $catend = $limit; 
} 

$i = 1;
$ii = 1;


?>




<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h2>
<form method="post" action="">  


<?php
  //Include Heureka CPC table
  include('modules/heureka_cz_cpc.php');


  //Include Heureka Shipping table
  include('modules/heureka_cz_shipping.php');


  //Display category setting paggination
  echo tax_pagination($cat_list, 50); 


  ?>

<!-- Heureka kategorie -->
<div class="t-col-12">
    <div class="toret-box box-info">
      <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?php _e('Přiřazení kategorií','woo-xml-feeds'); ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
      <p><?php _e('Zde můžete přiřadit všechny kategorie ve vašem obchodu, k jednotlivým kategoriím Heuréky. Pokud máte v eshopu větší množství kategorií, buďte prosím trpěliví, načtení může chvíli trvat. Po rozkliknutí výběru Heuréka kategorie, můžete do řádku zapsat počáteční písmena hledané kategorie a použít našeptávač.','woo-xml-feeds'); ?></p>

      <p><?php _e('Pokud nechcete zobrazovat zboží z určité kategorie v XML feedu, zaškrtněte "Vyloučit kategorii".','woo-xml-feeds'); ?></p>


        <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th><?php _e('Vyloučit kategorii', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('Kategorie obchodu', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('Kategorie na Heuréce', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
            <th><?php _e('CPC kategorie', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
          </tr>
   <?php 

   $catTerms = explode(',',$cat_list);
   $aa = 0; 
   foreach($catTerms as $c_item) : 
   if(!empty($c_item) && $i >= $catstart){
   if($i > $catend){ break; }
   ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="td_center"><input class="icheck_red" type="checkbox" name="excluded[<?php echo $aa; ?>]" <?php if(!empty($heureka_excluded_categories[$c_item])){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $c_item; ?>" ></td>
        <td>
          <?php
          $aa++;
          $catTerm = get_term_by( 'id', $c_item, 'product_cat' );
          if(!empty($catTerm->parent)){
          $p_name = get_term_by( 'id', $catTerm->parent, 'product_cat' );
          echo $p_name->name.' >> ';

          } 

          ?> <?php echo $catTerm->name; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="termid[]" value="<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php 
          if(!empty($use_select2) && $use_select2 == 'no'){}else{ 
        ?>
          <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("#heureka<?php echo $i; ?>").select2(); });
          </script>
        <?php } ?>  
        <style>#s2id_heureka<?php echo $i; ?>{min-width:800px;}</style>
          <select name="heurekaid[]" id="heureka<?php echo $i; ?>">
          <option value="default"></option>
            <?php
              foreach($heureka_categories as $key => $item){ 
              if(!empty($item['category_fullname'])){
              ?> 
            <option <?php if(!empty($heureka_assing_categories[$catTerm->term_id]) && $heureka_assing_categories[$catTerm->term_id]==$key){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }; ?>value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $item['category_fullname']; ?></option>  
            <?php  }
            }
            ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="category_cpc[]" value="<?php if(!empty($heureka_categories_cpc[$c_item])){ echo $heureka_categories_cpc[$c_item]; } ?>" style="width:40px;" /></td>
    </tr>
   <?php 
   }
   $i++;
   endforeach; 
   ?> 
   </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Heureka kategorie parametry -->
  <div class="t-col-12">
    <div class="toret-box box-info">
      <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?php _e('Vlastní parametry pro kategorie','woo-xml-feeds'); ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
        <table class="table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th><?php _e('Kategorie eshop', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
            <th style="width:80%;"><?php _e('Vlastní parametry', 'woo-xml-feeds'); ?></th>
          </tr>
   <?php 
   $catTerms = explode(',',$cat_list);
   foreach($catTerms as $c_item) : 
   if(!empty($c_item) && $ii >= $catstart){
   if($ii > $catend){ break; }
   ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
          <?php
          $catTerm = get_term_by( 'id', $c_item, 'product_cat' );
          if(!empty($catTerm->parent)){
          $p_name = get_term_by( 'id', $catTerm->parent, 'product_cat' );
          echo $p_name->name.' >> ';

          } 

          ?> <?php echo $catTerm->name; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="termvar[<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td class="category_params">
          <?php 
            if(!empty($cat_params[$catTerm->term_id]['parametry'])){
              foreach($cat_params[$catTerm->term_id]['parametry'] as $lit => $var){ ?>
                 <fieldset>
                  <input type="text" name="nazev_parametru_<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>[]" placeholder="Název parametru" value="<?php echo $var['nazev_parametru']; ?>" />
                  <input type="text" name="hodnota_parametru_<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>[]" placeholder="Hodnota parametru" value="<?php echo $var['hodnota_parametru']; ?>"/>
                  <span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-param"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
                 </fieldset>
            <?php }
            }
          ?>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <span class="btn btn-danger btn-sm add-param"data-par="<?php echo $catTerm->term_id; ?>">Přidat parametr</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
   <?php 

   }
   $ii++;
   endforeach; 
   ?> 
        </table>
      <input type="hidden" name="update" value="ok" />
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning" value="<?php _e('Uložit nastavení','woo-xml-feeds'); ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>       


</form>


</div>
```

I really tried to google it I found similar problems with some simple advice to switch to default theme or to put `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to wp-config.php. No luck with any of these.